# Check if user holds key c# metro app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

How can I detect if a user is holding a certain key?

Using a global KeyDown event would not do the job, because this only triggers at being pressed down, like so:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;
}

private void CoreWindow_KeyDown(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.Right)
    {
        // Logic
    }
}
```

Is there any way to continuously detect if the key is down or hold? Perhaps in a timer of some sort that checks every milisecond if the key is down?

It could be something like this; however the "right"-variable does not provide with ways to see if it's down. The GetKeyState returns a "CoreVirtualKeyStates". But I can not seem to enumerate through this. According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corevirtualkeystates) link, if the states value is 1, the key is down. But how can I check against this?

If I could check that, the answer would be very easy:

```
private void MoveTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    var right = Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Right);
    if(right == 1)
        // Logic
}
```

How can I detect if a key is being hold (or continuous down with a timer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my own solution: I can check `right` against `CoreVirtualKeyStates`

```
private void MoveTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    var right = Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Right);
    if (right == CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down)
    {
        //Logic
    }
}
```

This does open up more questions but this issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `flag` can be set from the key up event:

```
private void CoreWindow_KeyUp(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.Right)
    {
        right=0
    }
    else
    {
     right=1
    }
}
```

and thus in your timer your check `right` flag:

```
private void MoveTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    var right = Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Right);
    if(right == 1)
        // Logic
}
```

Comment: Right actually becomes a [CoreVirtualKeyStates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corevirtualkeystates)  value. But this does not achieve the smoothness of what I am trying to achieve, the one milisecond timer is not good enough. You can check against 3 CoreVirtualKeyStates, so my initial question is resolved but opens up another.